# Load images in QLabel

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel, qscrollarea, imagesloaded

How to show more number(folder) of images in Qlabel or QScrollArea?

```
QImage image("E:/Raul/Images");
  ui.label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
```

Like this but i want more number images will load in one label.

Comment: I don't think you can have more than one image per QLabel.  You could create multiple QLabels though, and put one image in each of them.

Comment: Noo we can that, And when im scroll my scroll bar automatically change image in same Qlabel.

Comment: Yes, you can change the image in a QLabel; but you can't have two images in the same QLabel at the same time.

Comment: @SaiRaul, your comment says that it is possible to do so even thou setPixmap suggests that you can set only one. Please, explain why you thing it is possible.

Comment: Here we don't use in Qpixmap, We can do that by using QFileInfo and filePath(), absoluteFilePath(), and dir().

Comment: You can union your images using QPainter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result:

[image]

Code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPointer>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QWizardPage>

#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget widget;
    QVBoxLayout *layout=new QVBoxLayout();
    QLabel *label=new QLabel("<img src=:/0_0.jpg align=middle><img src=:/0_1.jpg align=middle><strong>Hello</strong> "
    "<font color=red>Sai Raul!");
    layout->addWidget(label);
    widget.setLayout(layout);
    widget.show();
    return a.exec();
    //
}
```

`QLabel` is not a web browser, therefore hyperlinks like `<img src=/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg/>` doesn't work, but why images from resources can not do it))).

Comment: @SaiRaul please mark my answer as accepted,  green check mark